# Same random sequence in VB and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, random, migration

I'm migrating an old application in VB6 to C# and I've find a problem with a random number sequence:

(pin is a number greater than 0 in string format)
In my VB code, I've found:

```
Rnd("-" & pin)
Randomize(CDbl(pin))
```

So, the code generates the same number sequence all the times (read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdhk2yh(v=vs.110).aspx) note)

Now, in my C# code, I have:

```
Random r = new Random(int.Parse(pin))
```

But it does not generate the same sequence.

I'm trying to avoid VBMath.Rnd() instruction, if it's possible.

Please, can you tell me what is the equivalent code in C#?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If it is random numbers you are looking for, why do you care that the sequence is the same?

Comment: I don't think the VB6 implementation of the RNG is the same as the .Net version.

Comment: @jdweng His problem is that the pseudo-random number generator of VB6 is different than the one of .NET, an he wants a C# implementation of the VB6 one, but he doesn't want to use `VBMath.Rnd()`

Comment: The note says following : To repeat sequences of random numbers, call Rnd with a negative argument immediately before using Randomize with a numeric argument. Using Randomize with the same value for Number does not repeat the previous sequence.

Comment: @the_lotus: It's true in C#, but it doesn't seem true in this case

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, I'll prefer not to use VBMath.Rnd() if it is possible...

Comment: Why don't you want to use the code that works?

Comment: @Tistkle A pseudo random number generator like that is not safe for encryption.  You should use cryptographic strength random number generators when doing encryption.  You should re-encrypt your data into a more secure encryption method.

Comment: @mjwills: It not depends on me... :(

Comment: What does that mean? What doesn't depend on you? If someone is telling you not to use a method, you need to ask them **why**. Because it seems very odd to want specific functionality that does a very specific certain thing, and Microsoft has **written** that functionality (and tested it etc etc) - yet you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various problems here:

- You decided you don't wan't to use Microsoft reimplementation of the `Random()`/`Rnd()` VB6 methods (from assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic`) and
- There is no complete, public documentation of the `Random()` function (there is a partial documentation of the `Rnd()` function, minus the part about reseeding using negative numbers [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/A_PRNG_for_VBA#Microsoft's_Rnd()_algorithm) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160325161416/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/231847))

Now... There is a reimplementation of the algorithm in VB.NET [here](https://gist.github.com/turbo/4a76421ffb4f89d8becb) that claims to be *VBMath Rnd() 1:1 Clone*,

*but* the problem is the legality of that gist... We don't know how the author reverse engineered the algorithm... If what you are doing is for private use, you clearly can use [IlSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) and take a look at the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly where you can find the whole algorithm (it is less than 100 lines of code, and `projectData.m_rndSeed` is 327680 as documented on the wiki). If you want, you don't even need to use IlSpy... Microsoft put the source code (written in vb.net) in its referencesource [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/Microsoft.VisualBasic/runtime/msvbalib/Math.vb), but note that the same legality problems apply: the code under referencesource is for browsing only.

Comment: Thanks to that, I have been able to argue in favor of Rnd use, and I won.
I'll mark this answer as correct.